# How to tell if a systemd-run service was killed/died versus exiting normally?

Tags: systemd

```
$ systemd-run sleep 1000
Running as unit: run-u635.service
```

If I kill the sleep process or even if I kill the service properly using:

```
$ systemctl kill run-u635.service
```

I cannot find any property of the unit which tells me that the process was killed versus exited normally.  eg.

```
$ systemctl show --property=ExecMainStatus run-u635.service
ExecMainStatus=0
```

How can I tell the difference between a service exiting normally and it being killed or crashing?

Comment: systemctl status run-u635.service ?

Comment: After the service has exited, the status is not available: `Unit run-u635.service could not be found.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run a service as `--service-type=oneshot` (`Type=oneshot`), then exiting with `SIGTERM` will be considered a failure.

This is actually the usual type, for a service like this one which runs a shell command or shell script.  (In contrast to a "daemon" which often runs "forever", or at least until the system is shut down).  While the command runs, the service will show as "starting", instead of showing as "started".  If you use `--remain-after-exit` (`RemainAfterExit=yes`), it will show as `started` when the command finishes.  Otherwise, it will be considered `stopped` when the command finishes.  You are creating a "transient" unit, so it will disappear when it is stopped.

You were happy that systemd-run did not wait for your command to finish.  (I note, if you had used `--wait`, it would have shown that the command exited with `SIGKILL`).  In this case, you could use a command like the following:

```
systemd-run --service-type=oneshot --no-block sleep 1000
```

If there is a failure, it will appear in the log messages.  You can view them using journalctl.  For example:

```
journalctl -b -u run-u635.service
```

If you wanted to use this approach in a script, it does not seem as good as the approach you hoped would work.  There might be a better combination of features you can use; I think it would depend on knowing more about what you want to achieve.

If you were using a user unit instead (`systemd-run --user ...`), then I would worry that there could have been other instances of `run-u635.service` from a previous login session.

---

The documentation appears to be incomplete here, at least on my system.  The documentation in `man systemd.service` does not appear to mention any possibility of changing the behaviour for `SIGTERM`.  In particular I notice the definition of `SuccessExitStatus=` mentions no such possibility.

In general, systemd does not assume that services catch SIGTERM.  Some services might not need to do anything when they are requested to terminate.  So, usually a service which exists with `WTERMSIG() == SIGTERM` will not be logged as an abnormal exit.  (In fact, [historically](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/6e2f5000c7a83e3cce336d07395463491fc5f16d) the systemd docs said that a service killed with SIGTERM should make sure that it exits with `WTERMSIG() == SIGTERM`, even if it *did* catch the signal).

This might sound surprising.  Remember that Unix & Linux has been used for decades *without* any service supervision.  Since the exit status of services was not monitored, there are almost certainly some services that exist with `SIGTERM` when stopped normally.

> After the service has exited, the status is not available: `Unit run-u635.service could not be found.`

Correct.  The fact that `systemctl show` *appeared* to work in this case, is just one example of how horribly confusing `systemctl show` can be :-(.  When you attempt to query any properties of a service which does not actually exist (or even one which is just not loaded at the moment), there is no error message, you just see default / null property values.  Except for the `LoadState` property - that is the only clue it gives you.

```
$ systemctl show --property=LoadState run-u635.service
LoadState=not-found
```

Comment: I think you may mean `--service-type=oneshot`.  However the behaviour of this is even stranger: It runs in the foreground and there's no way to status of the service.  If I change the command to `bash -c 'sleep 1000 &'` then it appears to start up, prints the unit name, but there is no sleep running and the unit name cannot be queried.

Comment: Oh wait, `journalctl -u ...` finds the service but `systemctl status ...` does not.  This is crazily inconsistent.

Comment: Oh I see again; with `bash -c 'sleep 1000 &'`, bash process is exiting immediately and the container kills off the sleep.

Comment: Got it, the final answer is to use `systemd-run --service-type=oneshot --no-block sleep 1000` which behaves as I want.

Comment: You still need `--service-type` (not `--service`) but basically yes that's the answer, thanks.

Comment: @Rich it actually worked either way, but the longer one is much clearer. So I folded that into a larger edit.